# Multiple matches on split-string

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm using the split()-function on an hexlified string in Python. This string is containing a marker (0xffffffffffffffff) which I want to split out. After this marker there is hexadecimal data. There can be multiple "markers" in the hexlified string.

Now I found out that there is a problem when my first data-string ends with "ff" and the next marker is directly following it (Which happens not often, but it happens).

Is there any way to split "right-bound"?

```
0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0a 0b 0c ...
```

In this case I want the string splitted as following:

```
0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f ->ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff<- 0a 0b 0c ...
```

But it is splitted like this:

```
0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0 ->f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff f-> f 0a 0b 0c ...
```

Any idea how I can achieve it in python?

Current code is pretty simple:

```
a = "0a0b0c0d0e0fffffffffffffffff0a0b0c"
list = a.split("ffffffffffffffff")

[0]: 0a0b0c0d0e0
[1]: f0a0b0c
```

But it should be:

```
[0]: 0a0b0c0d0e0f
[1]: 0a0b0c
```

Comment: I can't tell without code, but `rsplit()` comes to mind.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 has a good hint ;-) what took me some time, was: The spaces separating the 2 digit packs are only injected in that question text, but in the real input, the data is **not** separated by spaces, right?

Comment: @Dilettant That's correct. The whitespace is just applied for better readability. The "real string" is without any whitespace.

Comment: @TobiasH.: which version of Python are you using? Are you comfortable working with bytes?

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you were working with the binary data instead of a hexlified string...

Comment: Adding to the others' comments: It may come the day, where some "payload" to the right "starts" with f (in your rep) so even `rsplit` might not solve, but bytes taking always the full info do not have this partial match problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring Can you use `split()` on binary data?

Comment: Maybe use the index or find method on it i.e. a bytearray(source.read()) ...? And then slice and dice based on that ...

Comment: @TobiasH. Sure. Here's an example which works on Python 2 or 3: `b'abc\xffdef'.split(b'\xff')`

Comment: @PM2Ring Great, thank you! Managed it to get it working with your tip!

Comment: Ah, so it _was_ an [XY probblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your string to `bytes`/`bytearray` and split it

```
In [2]: b = bytes.fromhex(s).split(b'\xff'*8)

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [b'\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f', b'\n\x0b\x0c']
```

Then convert each element of the list back to `str`

```
In [4]: [x.hex() for x in b]
Out[4]: ['0a0b0c0d0e0f', '0a0b0c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps: First, group the digits into pairs, then split by 8 groups of `ff`:

```
>>> a = "0a0b0c0d0e0fffffffffffffffff0a0b0c"
>>> b = re.sub(r"(?<=\w{2})(\w{2})", r" \1", a)
>>> re.split(r"(?:ff ){8}", b)
['0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f ', '0a 0b 0c']
```

Optionally, join the results back together:

```
>>> [s.replace(" ", "") for s in _]
['0a0b0c0d0e0f', '0a0b0c']
```

Of course, this will still fail in case the first number ends with `ff` or the second number starts with `ff`, but I don't think there is any way around that.

Answer (score 0):

To parse a hexadecimal 8-bit number sequence properly, you simply must treat it as characters pairs.

The following simple split function splits a string on a fixed substring, but only at even positions. It preserves the pairs of chars that form the hex numbers.

```
def split_even(string, sep):
    index = 0
    while index >= 0:
        index = string.find(sep, index)
        if index == -1:
            yield string
        elif index % 2:
            index += 1
        else:
            yield string[:index]
            string = string[index + len(sep):]
            index = 0


hexs = "001f" + "ffff" + "f23344" + "ffff" + "55"
ffs = "ffff"
print(list(split_even(hexs, ffs)))
# ['001f', 'f23344', '55']
```